# Missing model class when adding a view in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, strongly-typed-view

In my ASP.NET MVC 3 project i have a reference to my DomainModel project.

The problem occurs when i try to create a strongly-typed view. In the model class list my models from the DomainModel doesn't exist.

I did the try the following with no success(From another thread):

```
-remove reference to the library containing the model
-clean project
-close VS
-reopen VS
-rebuild project (VS throws errors)
-re-add reference to the model library
-rebuild project
```

I also tried to update VS2010 to VS2010 SP1 same problem.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I only seem to have this problem when my models are in a separate class library.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you cannot see the model in the dialog box try to directlly call it from the view like this:

```
@model  IEnumerable<Ieagle.WebSelfCare.Models.InvoicingIndex>
```

In case you have an IEnumerable Model otherwise

```
@model Ieagle.WebSelfCare.Models.Person
```

If you cant reach your models like this than you may have problems within the models

Comment: I have no problem when i input the model myself, i just get tired of why it didn't work in the add view dialog box